# How to avoid HTTP 405 in .net core for HttpPost and HttpGet

Tags: .net-core, routes

I have two actions one GET and POST, GET with route attribute as below:

```
[Route("{culture}/Users/[controller]/Edit/{userFullName?}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(string userFullName, string cultureCode = CultureData.DEFAULT_LANG)
```

and Post as below:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(UserViewModel model)
```

the view contains the following form

```
<form asp-action="Edit" asp-controller="Profile" asp-area="Users" asp-route-culture="@culture" asp-route-userFullName=" @UserExtension.ReturnSeperatedFullName(Model.FirstName, Model.SecondName, Model.ThirdName)"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

When I hit submit button it gives

> HTTP ERROR 405

I know it's a routing issue cause the GET edit action has a different route. how to solve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: {userFullName?} > the nullable userFullName looks suspicous for me. May the nullable is messing up because if it is required (and present) it is clear it goes to the GET and if not present it always points to the POST.

If it is nullable the missing userFullName allows two ways in my opinion

Comment: Actually, I remove the nullable from the parameter and it seems to be the same.